# @Qualifier annotation is not working in Spring for me, everything looks fine

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-mvc, annotations

I am using `@Qualifier` along with `@Autowired` but it giving me this exception:

```
Exception: 
  No qualifying bean of type 'com.springcore.autowiring.annotation.B' 
  available: expected single matching bean but found 2: b1,b2.
```

The class `A` where I am trying to autowire obj of `B`:

```java
public class A {
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("b2")
    private B b;

    public A( B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A ["+this.b+"]";
    }
    
    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    
}
```

It is working fine when using just `@Autowired` only with one bean of type `B`.

##### This is the class `B`:

```java
public class B {

  private String name;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "B [name=" + name + "]";
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

##### This is my `config.xml`:

```xml
<context:annotation-config /> <!-- this is our bean metadata -->
<bean class="com.springcore.autowiring.annotation.B"
      id="b1"
      name="b1"
      p:name="Xyz" />
<bean class="com.springcore.autowiring.annotation.B"
      id="b2"
      name="b2"
      p:name="Abc" />
<bean class="com.springcore.autowiring.annotation.A"
      name="ObjA"> </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thi is class B:```
public class B {
 private String name;

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "B [name=" + name + "]";
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think spring is confusing the field injection and the contructor in class A.
So if you want to use field injection, remove the constructor in class A.
Or you can use constructor injection like this.

```java
public class A {
    private B b;

    @Autowired 
    public A(@Qualifier("b2") B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using @Autowired on the constructor and @Qualifier("b2") on the constructor argument, like this:

```
public class A {

private B b;

@Autowired
public A(@Qualifier("b2") B b) {

    this.b = b;
}

public B getB() {
    return b;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "A ["+this.b+"]";
}

public void setB(B b) {
    this.b = b;
}
```

}

It work for me.

Comment: If you are using Lombok to generate the `@Autowired` annotated constructor, make sure to use `@Qualifier` annotation on variable name, use  `Lombok v > 1.18` and `@Qualifier` to copyable annotation